# Trouble making a jTable invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtable

For most items within Java, you simply add `.setVisible(false)`. Then the item disappears from the form, but when I do this for a `Jtable` within `Netbeans`,  using:

```
table1.setVisible(false);
```

Rather the table going invisible, it goes grey instead. Shown in picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60iNs.png]

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to call `reset()` and `revalidate()` on the container that holds the JTable after making it invisible.
- You shouldn't be making it invisible anyway, yes perhaps the JScrollPane that holds it, but not the JTable itself.
- You've misspelled "Length".